# R function with some default argument dependent on other argument

Tags: r, function, dependencies, arguments, default

I have a function with one default argument depending on another argument. And I have some strange behaviour. In the example the argument is `colheads=colnames(data)` which depends on `data`.

```
aaa <- head(iris)
fun <- function(data, colheads=colnames(data), rownames=1:nrow(data), rownames.label="Rowlabel"){
       data <- cbind(rownames, data)
       colnames(data) <- c(rownames.label, colheads)
}
fun(aaa)
```

Here I get an error on the last line `colnames(data)`. It looks like the `colheads` argument is updated because `data` itself is updated the line before.

Because if I try to run this code without function, there is no error.

```
data <- aaa
colheads <- colnames(data)
rownames.text <- 1:nrow(data)
rownames.label <- "Rowlabel"
data <- cbind(rownames, data)
colnames(data) <- c(rownames.label, colheads)
```

Then I tried to add some `print` within the function to check where it happens (the `debug` function also spots the last line). With this, I still get the error. Again, looks like `colheads` is updated.

```
aaa <- head(iris)
fun <- function(data, colheads=colnames(data), rownames=1:nrow(data), rownames.label="Rowlabel"){
       data <- cbind(rownames, data)
       print(colheads)
       colnames(data) <- c(rownames.label, colheads)
}
fun(aaa)
```

But if I also add a `print` before `data` is updated, the error disappears.

```
aaa <- head(iris)
fun <- function(data, colheads=colnames(data), rownames=1:nrow(data), rownames.label="Rowlabel"){
       print(colheads) 
       data <- cbind(rownames, data)
       print(colheads)
       colnames(data) <- c(rownames.label, colheads)
}
fun(aaa)
```

I found a workaround using a temporary variable `colheads.temp` below.

```
aaa <- head(iris)
fun <- function(data, colheads=colnames(data), rownames=1:nrow(data), rownames.label="Rowlabel"){
       colheads.temp <- colheads       
       data <- cbind(rownames, data)
       colnames(data) <- c(rownames.label, colheads.temp)
}
fun(aaa)
```

But still, as I am unsure about how R functions work, I am puzzled. Do someone knows what is going on and how R functions actually work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is called **lazy evaluation**. The argument `colheads=colnames(data)` is not evaluated until `colheads` is used inside the function. And it will use the current value of `data` at the time it is evaluated. This is nice, because if `colheads` is never called, then it is never evaluated, making code faster (it has other benefits too, but also drawbacks).

The `force` function is made to formalize your workaround, `force(colheads)` as one of the first lines of your function would force the evaluation and lock in the definition of `colheads` with the current value of the data.

If you'd like to learn more, I'd suggest reading the **Functions** chapter of *Advanced R*, [or at least the section on lazy evalatuion](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation).